# R legend with the same intervals height independently of the distance between breaks

Tags: r

I have to plot a raster using R, but the distance between breaks is not the same:

```
400 500 750 1000 1500 2000
```

This results in a legend that has a height between breaks proportional to them. But I want the same height independently of the distance between breaks.

I show you the objective I have in mind:

[image: Legend_objective]

Comment: I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve the solution.

```
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("orange","cornsilk","green","cyan3","purple4","blueviolet"))
num_intervals=14 cuts=c(400,500,750,1000,1500,2000) 

#to plot the data
plot(my_raster, breaks=cuts, col = pal(num_intervalos),axis.args=arg,legend=FALSE) 

#after that, I include the legend:

image.plot( zlim=c(0,750),lab.breaks=cuts,legend.only=TRUE,col = pal(num_intervals))
```